# How to Remove - Modify btn-inverse Top Border

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

can you please let me know how I can remove or change the color of `.btn-inverse` located inside a `.well` div

Please take a look at following image:
[image]

I tried to update CSS of the `.btn-inverse` by settong to no border-top but that gray line still sitting there!

**UPDATE:**
Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/z28VX/2/)

```
.btn-inverse {
 border-style:none !important;
 }
```

As you can see I set the border style to none and it removes all borders but the gray line still there!

Comment: Please post your CSS, what you tried and your HTML

Comment: definitely need to see the css code for .btn-inverse to see what's happening here

Comment: This is why we need to see YOUR css. [fiddle of me removing this border without a problem](http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/yvXdc/3/)

Comment: You probably aren't using a strong enough rule.

Comment: Hi All , thanks for reply, please look at update for demo link and code

Comment: @feitla, thanks for demo but after setting the .well styles to what I have in original it also displays the grey line!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
.well .btn-inverse {
border-top:none!important;
}
.btn {
box-shadow:none!important;
}
```

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/H6zK7/

Comment: Thanks , but What is that box shadow!

Comment: its shadow on the box ;) its light grey, so looks like a border a bit. its set somewhere on the .btn class.

Comment: Thanks again, but can someone let me know why did i get -3 on this question?!

Comment: Probably because you didn't include code at first. I voted you up, its a good question with pictures and demo.